# Shortcuts Issue

Tags: siri, shortcuts-app

I've had this working, but then it started messing up and now it won't perform at all.

1. I can ask for "Hey Siri:  Water Log"
2. It gives me a visual "What's the text?" and I say "Nine".  This last request now keeps asking me and it doesn't write to the Note.

How can I fix this?  Am I using the wrong Actions?

[image]